# Buying selling of cryptocurrency. Where does the coin come from and where does it go?

Tags: exchanges, trading, buy-bitcoins, sell-bitcoins

I am a novice trying to understand selling and buying of crypto currency. I could not find it on google so asking, please do not be harsh.

Say, I have an account with coinbase and want to buy bitcoins or other cryptocurrency, how does/where from an exchange gets those coin to sell to me? and If I want to sell my coins whom does the exchange sell it to.

Is there an article on how this trade work on the internet?

Comment: A coin exchange is much like a stock exchange: individual traders bring their coins to the exchange to make trades. So are you asking "what are the names of some of these traders" or "how does a new coin get created" or "how does a new exchange attract its first trader" or "how does a basic transaction work (note that you can do transactions without exchanges)" ... It could help to focus your question a bit.

Answer (score 1):

> I am a novice trying to understand selling and buying of crypto currency. I could not find it on google so asking, please do not be harsh.

No worries, we all start out here.

> Say, I have an account with coinbase and want to buy bitcoins or other cryptocurrency, how does/where from an exchange gets those coin to sell to me?

They already have a good stock of Bitcoins ready to sell you.

> and If I want to sell my coins whom does the exchange sell it to.

It is different for some exchanges. Some will buy them directly from you to get stock of them, and others will put them up for other users to buy, and the exchange will act as a middleman.

> Is there an article on how this trade work on the internet?

Yes, a simple search should provide you with many resources.

**Hope this helped!**

Answer (score -1):

The very, very first coins are minted and created through the process of mining. Then it's a series of transactions that move them around.

There are TONS of articles and books out there. You probably want to research a little before asking here.

Comment: I am sorry, and you are right .... I just found one. Thank you.